# Samba - On share is accessible, the other with same settings is not

Tags: networking, permissions, samba

I have two samba shares. One is accessible, the other is not. What could be the issue? Here is the config:

The smb.conf

```
[patrick]
path = /media/network_data/patrick
valid users = patrick
browsable =yes
read only = no
writeable = yes
guest ok = no
create mask = 0600
directory mask = 0700

[veronika]
path = /media/network_data/veronika
valid users = veronika
browsable =yes
read only = no
writeable = yes
guest ok = no
create mask = 0600
directory mask = 0700
```

The Id's

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ id patrick uid=1001(patrick) gid=1001(patrick)
groups=1001(patrick),1006(smbusers) ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ id veronika
uid=1002(veronika) gid=1003(veronika)
groups=1003(veronika),1006(smbusers) ubuntu@ubuntu:~$
```

[User Colors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TwdQQ.png)

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:/$ su - veronika
Password: 
su: warning: cannot change directory to /home/veronika: No such file or directory
veronika@ubuntu:/$
```

I saw when that the user Veronika has another color in the bash than patrick or root. What does this mean? Could this be the issue?

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue. I had no SMB User created for the user Veronika.

So had to do following:

> sudo smbpasswd -a veronika

> sudo systemctl restart smbd.service

Hope helps somebody else.